# Im trying to use activation window on winform C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use an activation window on my project when it starts. trying to disappear a activation window if correct product key is applied.
I'm coding as like
{

```
     private void btnactivate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (activation key == "123456789")
                MainForm frm = new MainForm();
                this.Hide();
                frm.Show();
                      //(Now this project shouldn't ask for an activation again) 
else
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to activate the software");

        }

 private void btntrial_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 MainForm frm = new MainForm();`enter code here`
                this.Hide();
                frm.Show();
}
```

}

Comment: Please see [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Generally you need to supply some code detailing what you have attempted. This is not a code generation site.

Comment: Why are you yelling so much? Slow down, post a [MCVE] and you will get our help.

Comment: thanks it was my first question so that .....I will try my best from next...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let me paraphrase your problem.

You want to display an activation form when the program starts. If the user clicks "Activate", the main form, instead of the activation form, would appear next time at the start of the program. But if he/she clicks on the "Trial", the activation form would still show up the next time the program starts.

This means that you will have to store whether the user has activated the software. The easiest way to do this is to store a file somewhere and check it each time. For this example, I will store a file in the `AppData` folder.

In the `Main()` in (probably) `Program.cs`, check if the file exists:

```
if (File.Exist(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\YourProgramName\\data.dat")) {
   Application.Run (new MainForm());
}
```

If it does not exist, show the `ActivationForm`

```
...
} else {
    Application.Run (new ActivationForm())
}
```

In the `btnactivate_Click()`, create the file if the key is correct:

```
if (...) {
    ...
    File.Create(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\YourProgramName\\data.dat");
}
```

And `Create` would create a `FileStream` also, so close that:

```
File.Create(...).Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this is C# winforms, and if it is, you would do this in the `Form.Load` Event, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information. This "Occurs before a form is displayed for the first time."

Hope that helps!

Comment: Actually, you should edit `Main()`